# How do I send mail using mailchimp key and id in ASP.NET C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

i want send mail (text and document) using mailchimp in asp.net c# for this. I download dll file (v3.0 API) from nuget and generate key and Id form mailchimp website.I Also Add API key in webconfig file now i can't  implement code for send mail using mailchimp in  cs page in asp.net c#..

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using MailChimp.Net;
public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   MailChimpManager manager = new MailChimpManager("string for API Key");



}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For any tool implementation/integration one should refer the original documentation of that tool.

However you can refer this github project for reference but I am not sure whether it will completely fulfill your requirement or not.

https://github.com/danesparza/MailChimp.NET

Comment: I can't understand their code.  mandrill is  use full for send mail